# How thick should I make my walls for stable 3D printing on an Elegoo Saturn?

Tags: 3d-models, support-structures, elegoo-mars

If I'm printing buildings that are about 2-3 inches high as scenery on my Elegoo Saturn, how thick should I make the walls? We're talking square boxy-type buildings with basic surface details.

I don't want to make them solid because that would put a lot of material on my FEP at the same time.

Comment: For what filament material and what size nozzle aperture?

Comment: It's an elegoo saturn. Resin not filament

Comment: 2-3 inches is... about Z to N Scale?

Answer (score -1):

Unless you can print the buildings upside down, limited details on roof, overhang will be more of an issue than wall thickness.

Comment: The Elegoo saturn is a mono resin printer, so everything is printed upside down. Its easier to make the roofs on their own and then glue them on.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have experience with resin printers.